# Como Montar um slide

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Precisava fazer um mini slide que contém uma imagem e um texto ao lado. Que passe automaticamente e quando clicar no botão. Alguém teria uma boa referência ou teria conhecimento para fazer isso? Eu montei a imagem de como ficaria meu slide.

*OBS: O slide está marcado de vermelho.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu faria com bootstrap, que é simples para quem tem conhecimento em front-end.

Comment: provavelmente vc não vai querer fazer do zero.. eu recomendo OWL Carousel http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer fazer do zero, veja: http://tableless.com.br/criando-slideshow-zero-com-javascript-puro-2/

Eu usaria o Prezi é uma ótima ferramenta para confecção de slides: https://prezi.com/

Comment: Celso, links podem deixar de existir. Seria melhor acrescentar pelo menos alguma informação relevante do tutorial na sua resposta. Abraço!